# Admitting to Multiple Things

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to say that a character has admitted past mistakes, and that in doing so, he's effectively admitted to being incompetent. Here's the relevant part of one of my sentences:

"[...] doing so would be an admission of past mistakes, and thus incompetence."

Is it necessary to change it to "and thus of incompetence" or "and thus to incompetence" to make it clear that the act of admitting mistakes itself does not reveal incompetence? If so, is "of" or "to" preferable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "... doing so would be an admission of past mistakes, and thus incompetence."

That is perfectly correct. In full it would be:

(a) *"... doing so would be an admission of past mistakes, and thus [an admission of] incompetence."*

If however you want to  admit **to** incompetence you are attempting to bring forward a smaller set of words. So...

(b) *"... doing so would be an admission of past mistakes, and thus to incompetence."*

would be an abbreviation of:

(c) *"... doing so would be an admission of past mistakes, and thus [an admission] to incompetence."*

However (b)  and (c) both sound wrong. It's difficult to say why other than by appealing to idiom. We say

*Are you willing to admit **to** X?*

but

*Are you willing to make an admission **of** X?*

The reason for the latter is because there is another idiom that clashes, i.e. 'to admit someone **to** some place'.

Looking at the following ngram you can see that usage has changed drastically in the last hundred years. The apparent popularity of 'admission to' is due to the other idiom I mentioned.

[Google ngram: admission to,admission of,admit to,admit of](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admission%20to%2Cadmission%20of%2Cadmit%20to%2Cadmit%20of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadmission%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadmission%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadmit%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadmit%20of%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Comment: That still seems unclear to me. Would it be acceptable to insert "of" into the sentence?

Comment: Yes, that would be acceptable as well. I'll add to my answer. I missed the part about 'to'.